# Undefined is not an object _expo.camera.constant when using expo Camera SDK

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I created a `RN` project with `create-react-native-app (CRNA)`. I want to use the `Camera API` provided by `expo`. In doing so, I simply copied the example here https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera.html and included the `Component`. Starting the App gives me the following: `Undefined is not an object _expo.camera.constant` with a massive stacktrace... Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: Please give some code example from your code

Comment: @bennygenel I exactly copy & pasted (as written in the Q) the component example given by `expo`.

Comment: Did you set the permissions needed for Camera usage?

Comment: @bennygenel where would I set them? In the code it looks like they are set here `const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });`

Comment: Yeah you are right. I can't see anything wrong. Its like expo is not installed. I don't have any idea. I'm sorry

Answer (score 3):

For those that are having problems with the camera set up. Just change: `import {Camera, Permissions}` ... by these lines:

```
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
```

You will need to install the camera so you need to install using this command:

```
expo install expo-camera
```

Now just run your app and Cheers!

Comment: I only needed to add `import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';`. The permissions were then handled with `Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue trying to use Expo Camera API into a CRNA project. I manage to access the Camera API with an Expo SDK upgrade. Here are the steps I followed:

1. In `app.json` change my Expo SDK version : `"sdkVersion": "20.0.0",`
2. In `package.json`change my current dependencies for Expo, React and React Native:

`"expo": "20.0.0-alpha.4",
 "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
 "react-native":"https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-20.0.0.tar.gz",`

3. Delete my `node_modules`folder
4. Run `npm install` again

These steps didn't break the packager: I still can launch my project with `npm start` and from Expo XDE. Though, I didn't take time to test side effects, particularly for the eject process provided by CRNA.

I could only advice to test this fix on a not-for-production app.

Nonetheless, hope this could help!

Comment: I simply switched to `react-native init`. Works out of the box that way. You can reuse the code youve written with `CRNA`.